# How to add the two names in application tag using Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using android eclipse and I want to add both volley jar and Google Cloud Message in my App. Also, I want to add these two names in application tag. I already know that we can use application tag only once in Manifest file. Is there any other way to add these two libraries in my App?

```
android:name="com.google.gcm.Controller" // This is for GCM
android:name="volley.AppController" // This is for Volley
```

Comment: Why in application tag when You app can have only one name? Maybe You want to name different activities?

Comment: As an additional question. Which volley dependency do you use? As far as i can see the source of volley does not include an `AppController.java` https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I extends the Application to AppController.java(volley)

```
public class AppController extends Application
```

Next I extends the AppController to Controller.java(GCM)

```
public class Controller extends AppController
```

Finally I added the name in application tag is GCM controller name

```
android:name="com.google.gcm.Controller"
```

Now its working for me.  Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filec), only one application tag can be inserted in the manifest.

**Quote from doc:**

> Only the manifest and application elements are required, they each
>   must be present and can occur only once.

I can understand your consequence and I think the solution is to merge the code of both classes(`controller and AppController`) in a single one.

Comment: Hi Mohammad Arman, Controller and AppController are different lib classes, Also I can't merge both Classes. Thank for quick reply

Comment: I also had the exact same issue. What I have done is, created another class MasterController and coppied all the methods and classes from both controllers. Then I have deleted the 2 old controllers. It created errors. Then I have imported the new class in all the activities where it created error. And in the manifest just added android:name=".MasterController"

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one Application tag but that should be no problem.

Just create an `Application` extending from the `com.google.gcm.Controller` and add the required code for volley into it (This is the AppController from the [linked tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/). Yours is probably different)

```
package info.androidhive.volleyexamples.app;

import info.androidhive.volleyexamples.volley.utils.LruBitmapCache;
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

[Source](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

If you did so add `android:name=".AppController"` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`